# Atom editor - Open-in-browser Extension - Switch browser

Tags: browser, atom-editor

I'm struggling to find out how to switch browsers in the Atom open-in-browser extension. I've looked for settings but I'm stuck with code opening in Firefox

Atom V 1.46.0,
open-in-browser V 0.5.2,
Windows 10 - Default browser - Chrome

[image: No settings button]

Answer (score 0):

For my experience (and of course with ubuntu), it would be nice to have the plugin "open-in-browsers" (reachable via "Edit"=>"Preferences"=>"Packages", v0.0.30 in my case) configure the Atom "config.cson" (reachable via "Edit"=>"Config...") like this:

```
  "open-in-browsers":
    Chrome:
      path: "/snap/bin/chromium"
      tooltip: "Chromium"
    Firefox:
      path: "/usr/bin/firefox"
      tooltip: "Firefox"
    FirefoxDeveloper:
      path: "/usr/local/bin/firefox-dev"
      tooltip: "Firefox Developer"
    browsers: [
      "Chrome"
      "Firefox"
      "FirefoxDeveloper"
    ]
    defBrowser: "FirefoxDeveloper"
```

but that will not work.

With no better luck I tried [in "config.cson"]:

```
   "open-in-browsers":
     BrowserPlus: false
     Chrome: false
     ChromePortable:
       path: "/snap/bin/chromium"
       tooltip: "Chromium"
     Firefox: false
     FirefoxPortable:
       path: "/usr/local/bin/firefox-dev"
       tooltip: "Firefox Developer"
     IE: false
     Opera: false
     Safari: false
     SafariPortable:
       path: "/usr/bin/firefox"
       tooltip: "Firefox"
     browsers: [
       "ChromePortable"
       "FirefoxPortable"
       "SafariPortable"
     ]
     defBrowser: "SafariPortable"
```

Now I have:

```
  "open-in-browsers":
    BrowserPlus: false
    FirefoxPortable:
      path: "/usr/local/bin/firefox-dev"
      tooltip: "Firefox Developer"
    IE: false
    Opera: false
    Safari: false
    SafariPortable: {}
    browsers: [
      "Chrome"
      "Firefox"
      "FirefoxPortable"
    ]
    defBrowser: "FirefoxPortable"
```

Chromium (via snap in ubuntu: /snap/bin/chromium) and Firefox (via ubuntu apt: /usr/bin/firefox) are working, Firefox Developer does not start at the moment, but did. Some update seems to have destroyed the link between Atom and Firefox Developer?!

It would be a good idea to fill the Wiki in https://github.com/skandasoft/open-in-browsers, for all platforms (MacOS, Linux, Windows).